# Spoof Geolocation position.heading in Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, geolocation, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome DevTools you have the ability to [spoof a location](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/device-input-and-sensors) to return to the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation), by putting a lat/lon into the Sensors tab. This works well, but there doesn't seem to be a way to spoof the heading or speed or any of the other properties that are returned.

This makes testing anything that makes use of heading/speed rather difficult, as it just returns null when you override from DevTools. At the moment I am having to load my localhost application onto a real device, then unplug it, take it outside and wander round the streets, which is a little tiresome.

Does anyone know of a way to emulate the heading/speed properties without leaving my seat, either using other dev tools, a plugin or a code snippet.

Comment: I have the exact problem you described. Did you ever end up finding a solution?

Comment: same here, found anything?

Comment: @ianaz afraid not. If you're handy at coding and have some spare time you can try and write your own extension, but I've not had the time or inclination to try!